# Where is the problem coming from: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: node.js

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.url (:4200/main.js:18799)
    at __webpack_require__ (:4200/runtime.js:80)
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js (:4200/vendor.js:174760)
    at __webpack_require__ (:4200/runtime.js:80)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:4200/vendor.js:174394)
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node (:4200/vendor.js:174551)
    at __webpack_require__ (:4200/runtime.js:80)
    at Object.0 (:4200/main.js:18753)
    at __webpack_require__ (:4200/runtime.js:80)
    at checkDeferredModules (:4200/runtime.js:46)
```

I get this bug in the console, specifically here

```
module.exports = require("url");
```

Is this a Webpack bug?

Comment: Why is `Angular` tagged here? Are you attempting `module.exports = require("url");` client-side?

Comment: Try like this :  `module.exports.url = require("url");`